# What is the easiest cross-browser compatible way of creating gradients with CSS?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I noticed this being used by a service, and the effect looks super great

```
-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #E3EBF3, #D5E1ED) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the CSS property like you have in your question. Add the `-moz`, `-webkit` prefixes, then use it prefixless.

[IE's `filter` property can do gradients](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/15/css-gradients-for-all-web-browsers-without-using-images/). It is propriety, but it works :)

Comment: so as usual, i would need to define a few different styles to get it to work across browsers. =)

Comment: @ming yeow Yeah, but hey, at least IE can be forced to play nice :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

use modernizr and some if IE blocks at the top to add classes to your html tag so that you can provide valid HTML and CSS, and hacks&properties to those necessary.

for instance, in a gradient I've used in the past:

```
body {
background: #2688cf;
}
.cssgradients body{
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2688cf 0%, #2989d8 12%, #207cca 14%, #62a2d6 18%, #b9d5ea 28%, #ffffff 40%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2688cf), color-stop(12%,#2989d8), color-stop(14%,#207cca), color-stop(18%,#62a2d6), color-stop(28%,#b9d5ea), color-stop(40%,#ffffff));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2688cf 0%,#2989d8 12%,#207cca 14%,#62a2d6 18%,#b9d5ea 28%,#ffffff 40%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2688cf 0%,#2989d8 12%,#207cca 14%,#62a2d6 18%,#b9d5ea 28%,#ffffff 40%);
background: linear-gradient(top, #2688cf 0%,#2989d8 12%,#207cca 14%,#62a2d6 18%,#b9d5ea 28%,#ffffff 40%);
}

.ie6 body, .ie7 body, .ie8 body, .ie9 body {
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2688cf 0%,#2989d8 12%,#207cca 14%,#62a2d6 18%,#b9d5ea 28%,#ffffff 40%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2688cf', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 );
background: linear-gradient(top, #2688cf 0%,#2989d8 12%,#207cca 14%,#62a2d6 18%,#b9d5ea 28%,#ffffff 40%);
}
```